# How to keep my cat from sitting on my computer ventilation hole?

Tags: cats, behavior

Unfortunately, my computer has it's main ventilation hole situated on the top. Warm air comes out of this hole, which my cat absolutely loves to sit on. Once it does this, my computer is at risk of overheating since animal fur is an excellent insulator for heat. Moreover, the cat's fur can easily penetrate the small ventilation holes, which can cause damage once a sufficient amount is accumulated within the computer.

I have already tried:

- [putting a box next to the computer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard),
- throwing him away every time he tries to jump on the computer,
- threatening it with one of those "water sprinklers" (without actually sprinkling water on it of course),

but to no avail. The sweet warmth of the computer makes it keep coming back.

What can I do to keep him off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way to deal with this would be to get a new desk that has a slot to put the computer in. The cat won't be able to sit on it if the computer is competely enclosed by the desk.

Another option is to get a heated cat bed and put it close to your desk. The heated cat bed would probably be more comfortable than the computer, and it would help satisfy your cat's desire for more heat.

Keep the computer off when not using it, so it won't be warm.

Another option if you're tech savvy enough, is to replace the computer's case with one that ventilates out the back or side.

Answer (score 3):

Although you've accepted an answer, I'd like to share my experience but it's probably not a solution and it might work for you.

I used to have that issue too and one time by accident I left my old headset on the case till I put it away and I saw the cat struggle to find a way to sit. He tried it a few times and then stopped sitting on there for good. Although I removed the headset a few days later, he never returned.

So placing something over the exhaust that won't block it but also makes it impossible for the cat to lie down might help.